# counter in php do while loop

Tags: counter, increment, do-while

I am checking ( or want to check ) if the counter gets to 5 I want to reset the counter back to one and start again until all the records have been read,I have the following code on a test page:

```
<?php do {  
if ($count == 5) { $count = 1;}
echo $count;

echo "<div id=\"col$count\"><div id=\"col$count-content\"><img class=\"resetImg\"    name=\"colpic$count\" src=\"assets/images/student_artwork/thumb_" . $row_rsILU['ilu_artwork'] . "\" alt=\"\" style=\"background-color: #999966\"><br><br><span class=\"artistName\">" . $row_rsILU['ilu_fname'] . " " . $row_rsILU['ilu_lname'] . "</span>    <br><hr>
Concept Artist<br>
email@artistdomain.ca<br>
416-833-1111<br>
www.portfolio.ca<br>
</div></div>"; 
$count++;
} while ($row_rsILU = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsILU));  ?>
```

The record set has three records in it but the count always seems to stop at two and only shows the two images. I am checking the count and if it gets to 5, I want to reset it to 1 and start over again until the total records in the record set have been read. Maybe I am just getting tired but I cannot get this. Would appreciate anyones help on this.

Cheers,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you are trying to echo the row before actually fetching it (I mean the first iteration). Why not just use *while* loop instead?

```
<?php 
while ($row_rsILU = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsILU)) {  
    if ($count == 5) { $count = 1;}
    echo $count;

    echo "<div id=\"col$count\"><div id=\"col$count-content\"><img class=\"resetImg\"    name=\"colpic$count\" src=\"assets/images/student_artwork/thumb_" . $row_rsILU['ilu_artwork'] . "\" alt=\"\" style=\"background-color: #999966\"><br><br><span class=\"artistName\">" . $row_rsILU['ilu_fname'] . " " . $row_rsILU['ilu_lname'] . "</span>    <br><hr>
    Concept Artist<br>
    email@artistdomain.ca<br>
    416-833-1111<br>
    www.portfolio.ca<br>
    </div></div>"; 

    $count++;
}  
?>
```

Please let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Well, I changed the code to the following and now I only get one iteration and one record??

Answer (score 0):

Humm ... well now, this is embarrassing! Turns out there was a second, older SELECT statement in the code that I missed and so it was not returning one of the three records because it was not looking for it, based on the older SELECT statement. Sorry about that but thanks for your help.